# Books on Resources for learning Japanese

Tags: discussion, resources

Perhaps books should be split into "Readers"(?) and "Reference books". Current entry only contains reference books.  I am always on the look out for good readers, ideally with parallel text, to develop my "読解力” and can suggest some.

Perhaps "Audio books & other Readers"?

Comment: I retagged as discussion since the resource thread is maintained by the JLU community and not the StackExchange team.  My understanding is that feature-requests are for changes to the StackExchange software, though the tag excerpt doesn't exactly clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just one or two you want to add, just add them to the list as is.

If there are enough that it's going to double the size of the section, just add a Readers Section for the moment... probably using the ## notation

"

### Books

... current contents

### Readers

... the readers you want to add
"

If it gets unwieldy, I'll split it off at some point. Me and ジョン picked those categories more-or-less arbitrarily, but I'd like to see how big it gets before actually splitting it up.

---

Might I suggest a criteria for inclusion in that list, however? To qualify as a 'reader', the book needs to be written as one. In other words, the "Parallel Text" books (designed for foreigners) qualify, as do the "はじめての文学" books. But books that are simply "lower level", or "easier for foreigners to read" should probably not be included... or we'll be including everyone's first translation conquest on this list. :-)

Comment: Thanks I have added the title and one book for you check, although I not sure how to work the font colour function. Among others books I might add are Rapid Reading Japanese. Improving reading skills of intermediate and advanced students, which you might say is a text book and 中上級の日本語, which you might argue is a monthly magazine but for reading resources, I think this is the right place (?)